# Change HTML textbox pre-populated number to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with a textbox which looks up a value and pre-populates the text box with this number.

The number should be in something that looks like a currency format - for example 7.50 not 7.5

Is there a way to ensure the value that is entered automatically is changed always to have 2 decimal places?

Here is the code I have:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="bid_price" id="bid_price" class="text" value="{$auction->getMinBidPrice()}" {if !$logged || $auction->getTimeToStart() > 0}disabled="disabled"{/if}/
```

I'm a real beginner so an exact bit of code would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function - note that toFixed(2) does no rounding:

```
var input = $(".text");
input.bind('keyup mouseup', function (event) {
    if(event.keyCode !== 8){
       checkInput();
    }
});
input.change(function(){
    checkInput();
});
function checkInput(){
    input.val(parseFloat(input.val()).toFixed(2));  
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3fw2q7r/8/

If you want to include the script into your html page use a  tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = $(".text");
    input.bind('keyup mouseup', function (event) {
        if(event.keyCode !== 8){
          checkInput();
        }
    });
    input.change(function(){
        checkInput();
    });
    function checkInput(){
        input.val(parseFloat(input.val()).toFixed(2));  
    }
    checkInput();
});
</script>
```

If you want to enter numbers with more than one digit just leave the keyup/mouseup event empty: https://jsfiddle.net/h3fw2q7r/9/

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for being a complete newbie, but can I just place this code somewhere in the existing file and it should work? For instance - where do I put this code in relation to the line of code that is already in place?

Comment: In the same file your HTML code is ... into a script tag

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the code. I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I wrapped it in <input type="hidden" /> tags to hide it. Is there a place in the file I should place the code for efficiency or will anywhere work? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Actually this doesn't allow the user to edit this automatically entered text. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? Maybe then i understand your issue better.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create a Fiddle which would work with the external resource. On the JS Fiddle you posted above you cannot type in a value of your own choice. The text box should automatically be filled in and set to 2 decimal places, but the user should be able to override this value by typing in a number of their choice.

Comment: I just updated my jsfiddle and the code in the answer above. Check it out and try it. I think it should work now as you want it.

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much for your time helping me with this. I owe you a beer / coffee.

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon! It is impossible to enter a value like 99

Comment: I added another fiddle for you.

Comment: Thank you! This works in Chrome and Opera, but not Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: We will find a solution

Comment: jQuery is not the solution to questions unless OP is using it already. Posting answers that use jQuery when there is no jQuery tag attracts downvotes.

Comment: This is now working. I had the input type set as Number instead of text! Thanks.